# Aggregating raster from Combine Tool in Spatial Analyst--->Local?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst

I have a raster file created through the Combine tool (Spatial Analyst--->Local). The attribute table is showed below. Its resolution is roughly 10m. I would like to aggregate it to 50m with each aggregated cell (including 25 small cells) having the sum of those attributes (SFDVal, MFDVal, MHVal and etc.) from the 25 small cells. I tried several ways (aggregation, zonal etc) but it seems like all of them are working on the actual cell value of the combined raster, instead of other attributes. But I only want to get a sum aggregation on those attributes, not the cell value.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would create individual raster of each of the attributes and use these fields as the VALUE and then aggregate or similar.

Use Field Calculator to copy the value you need (SFDVal) to Value.

Then use aggregate to do as you want.

Repeat for each variable.